SSL encrypted stream
I have a site with a radio broadcast. The site is in http (port 80) and https (port 443). The stream is on the same domain, port 8001.
When accessing the site in https the stream is not loaded because it's not a secure connection. How can I make the stream https? I'm not sure if it has to be handled in the apache config or through darkice / icecast, the software that creates the stream.

Icecast supports TLS. I would not recommend to try to reverse proxy through Apache. If you absolutely have to run both on the same server then run Icecast TLS e.g. on port 8443
